# Is anonymous object instantiation possible in Java?

Tags: java

Can anyone tell me the difference between two the lines of code below ?

```
ArrayList<Car> dat;
dat = (new DataSource()).getCar();

DataSource ds = new DataSource();
dat = ds.getCar();
```

What does it mean to put `new DataSource()` in parentheses?

At the end, what is the result of dat in these two cases?

```
 ArrayList<Car> dat;

 ArrayList<Car> dat = new ArrayList();
```

***Note:**  The `getCar` helper function returns an ArrayList to `dat`.*

Comment: @Oleksiy - editing the title to correct the grammar might be a more useful thing to do than mocking it.  Not everyone has English as their first language.

Comment: @DavidWallace that's the problem, it's impossible to deduct the correct grammar from "Is anonymous object instantiate existed in java?" - it doesn't make any sense

Comment: Not impossible at all, as I have just demonstrated.  And you mean "deduce", not "deduct".

Comment: @Oleksiy Why not rather just correct the title than making fun of it?

Comment: What is the difference of putting (2)+3

Comment: I think it depends. As long as I know parentheses operand have a higher precedence than other operands, so my confusion was because of the parentheses. Beside, I never saw such a coding before.

Comment: @Oleksiy - I agree that the original title made no sense—but not just because the grammar was weird. The title did not (and still doesn't) at all match the question content. I think a more fitting title would be _What advantage does anonymous object instantiation have in Java?_ I think _huh?_ is a perfectly valid response to a question with a title that doesn't match the question itself—but you should probably follow it up with a sentence explaining why you're confused.

Comment: @DaoWen It's not just the title: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18840752/1. The quality of this question was so bad that it had to be changed 6 times by 5 different people; I'm not even sure if it's still the same question anymore... I think *huh* was the correct response - how else could I react to a question like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
ArrayList<Car> dat;
dat = (new DataSource()).getCar();
```

the parentheses are superfluous.  You can equally write

```
dat = new DataSource().getCar();
```

In the other version that  you cited, you're doing one extra thing - making a variable that refers to your `DataSource`, for possible later use.

In answer to your second question,

```
ArrayList<Car> dat;
```

does not create an object.  There's no `ArrayList` here, just a variable that doesn't reference anything.  On the other hand,

```
ArrayList<Car> dat = new ArrayList();
```

creates BOTH an `ArrayList` AND a variable referencing it.

Comment: i like the word, superfluous +1

Answer (score 4):

There is no practical difference between the two versions of the code you posted. `dat` will be the same value in both cases.

The second version of the code you posted is more readable to humans, so in terms of code maintenance and readability, you may want to use that version.

Also, in the first version, you won't be able to use the value of (new DataSource()) anywhere else since you are not storing a reference to the result of (new DataSource()). This of course is not an issue if you don't need the result anywhere else in your code.

As for the second part of your question, in java, you can think of `ArrayList<Car> dat;` to be the same as `ArrayList<Car> dat = null;`. When you declare a reference like that, it does not point to anything. When you declare it as `ArrayList<Car> dat = new ArrayList<Car>;` however, you are creating a new ArrayList object and making `dat` refer to it.

Comment: Thank you, Ameen.  And I think people marking down this question are being unnecessarily harsh.  1) You are correct: the two statements accomplish the same thing.  2) I think the OP was also asking "do I need to explicitly create a variable "DataSource ds" in order to call "ds.getCar()"?  The answer is "No".

Comment: @paulsm4 agreed; sometimes the people rush to downvoting :(

Comment: wowwwwwww i did not know that is English grammar question that I asked? I said this is my first time. why you are acting like childish people? instead of being supportive, you are trying to rectifying some mistakes that they are not even issues here. wowwwwwwww
may be this is not question for whoever marked me down, yet it was huge confusion for me wowwwwwww

Comment: @KickButtowski: and why are **you** ranting in an answer where folks are trying to help you. Consider taking a few deep breaths, appreciating the help you get, and ignoring everything else, and things will go a lot smoother for you.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference is that in the second example you retain a reference to the DataSource object for the duration of the method call. Also the outer parentheses are extraneous.